# Resetting CSS when leaving drop area (drag and drop uploading)

Tags: jquery, image, html, drag-and-drop

In my application I've implemented drag and drop uploading. When you're dragging and holding an image over the "drop area", the drop area changes appearance and a text tells you to drop the file shows up.

If I cancel dropping the file, the new CSS as well as the text is still there, and I need to refresh the page to get it back to normal. How can I reset the css to the normal state without refreshing the page?

Thanks in advance!

```
holder.ondragover = function () {
  var information = "<div id='infoText2'>" + "<span>Drop the image here!</span>";
  $('#holder').html(information);
  this.className = 'hover';
  return false;
};
// Rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the the div and remove the classname when you get a `ondragend` event

```
holder.ondragend = function () {
  $('#intoText2').remove();
  this.removeClass();
};
```

Comment: Your code worked fine except you should use ondragleave instead of ondragend.